# Issue in client server network

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am creating an client server architecture.

Here the client enters a number and the server return the multiplication table of that number.

Once the client enters end the server stops responding.

The server is not accepting the number from the user.

Advise the changed in the code for it to work completely.

// server

```
package p1;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Server Signing On");
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9000);

        Socket soc=ss.accept();
//               System.out.println("Done");
        BufferedReader nis = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        soc.getInputStream()
                )
        );
  //          System.out.println("Till");
    PrintWriter nos = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    soc.getOutputStream()
            )
            ), true);
           System.out.println("here"); 
    String s = nis.readLine(); 
    String ans = "";
    int no = 0;

    while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
    {

        no = Integer.parseInt(s); System.out.println("no = " + no);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
            ans += no + " * " + i + " = " + (no * i) + "\n";
        //    System.out.println(ans);
            nos.println(ans);
            System.out.println("Data sent");
        s=nis.readLine();
            ans = "";

    }
        System.out.println("Server Signing off");
            ss.close();
    }
 }
```

//client

```
    package p1;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000);
    System.out.println("Client Signing On");

    PrintWriter nos = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    soc.getOutputStream()
            )
            ), true);

    BufferedReader nis = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    soc.getInputStream()
            )
    );

    BufferedReader kin = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in
            )
    );

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    String a = kin.readLine();
    String s = "";

    while(!a.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
    {
        nos.println(a);
        while((s = nis.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        a = kin.readLine();
    //    System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
    nos.println(a);

     System.out.println("Client Signing Off");
     soc.close();
}

}
```

Comment: At client you have `System.out.println("Enter a number"); int a = Integer.parseInt(nis.readLine());` so you are asking for number but reading it from `nis` which is server stream, not console. If you want to let user enter number via console you can use `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: Hey @Pshemo could you please advise on the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did following changes in code and it worked.

//server

```
package p1;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Server Signing On");
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9000);

        Socket soc=ss.accept();

        BufferedReader nis = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        soc.getInputStream()
                )
        );

    PrintWriter nos = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    soc.getOutputStream()
            )
            ), true);

    String ans = "";
    String s = nis.readLine();

    while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
    {
    int no = Integer.parseInt(s);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
            ans += no + " * " + i + " = " + (no * i) + "  ";
            nos.println(ans);
           ans = "";
            s = nis.readLine();
    }
    nos.println(s);

        System.out.println("Server Signing off");
            ss.close();
    }
}
```

//client

```
package p1;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000);
    System.out.println("Client Signing On");

    PrintWriter nos = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    soc.getOutputStream()
            )
            ), true);

    BufferedReader nis = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    soc.getInputStream()
            )
    );

    BufferedReader kin = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in
            )
    );

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    String a = kin.readLine(); 

    while(!a.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
    {
        nos.println(Integer.parseInt(a));  
        String[] s = nis.readLine().split("  ");

        for(String x: s)
            System.out.println(x);


        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        a = kin.readLine();
    }

    nos.println(a);
     System.out.println("Client Signing Off");
     soc.close();
}

}
```